# GDrive command-line utility - How can I get the ID of a Google Drive file given its "friendly" file name?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, google-drive

I'm using the [GDrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) command line utility to download a file produced by a Google Docs script. The script runs in a Google Docs spreadsheet, which generates a file from the spreadsheet data. I can download the file with:

```
gdrive download --stdout 0Bz3Kt0tCTCQ3Zng0bHcABCDEFGH
```

but that requires me to know the ID of the file, which changes every time the file is generated, even though the "friendly" name I give it in the script is the same each time.

Is there a way (using the GDrive utility or other) of getting the ID to use as the download command argument given the friendly filename?

An alternative solution would be to force Google Drive to use the same ID for the new file, but I doubt there is any way for mortals to do that.

<sub>I realize you can have multiple files with the same friendly name, but the script that generates the new one cleans out all existing ones of the same name, so that shouldn't be an issue.</sub>